# How to persist iptables configuration on Amazon EC2 VPC NAT Ami?

Tags: amazon-ec2, iptables, nat, amazon-vpc

I have a small script like this to configure the iptables:

```
#!/bin/bash

PRE_STR="iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j DNAT"
FOR_STR="iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -j ACCEPT"


#####################################
# instances
CM="10.0.1.137"
MASTER="10.0.1.149"
MYSQL="10.0.1.83"
REPORTING="10.0.1.85"

#####################################
# Clear Iptables
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F

#####################################
# Forward to enable Internet on private nodes
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE


#####################################
# Port forwarding

forward()
{
        $PRE_STR --dport $1 --to $2:$3
        $FOR_STR --dport $3 -d $2
}

#what   from    to ip           to port
forward 3222    $CM             22
forward 7183    $CM             7183
forward 7180    $CM             7180

forward 3122    $MASTER         22
forward 8888    $MASTER         8888
forward 11000   $MASTER         11000

forward 2122    $MYSQL          22
forward 13306   $MYSQL          3306

iptables-save > /etc/firewall.conf
```

The question is, how to load the `/etc/firwall.conf` with the current iptables settings on the next startup?

On a normal Debian machine I would put a script that fires `iptables-restore < /etc/firewall.conf` it into the folder `/etc/network/if-up.d/iptables`. But this isn't available in this image.

So what is the correct why to load this `/etc/firewall.conf`?

AMI ID: ami-1de2d969

**Update:**

Is it ok to fire it in `iptables-restore < /etc/firewall.conf` in `/etc/rc.local`?

Source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-save-iptables-rules-or-settings/

Comment: This question comes up first for a Google query for "Amazon Linux AMI persist iptables", and it has two good answers that tell me exactly what I need to know. The question that this is a duplicate of has neither. Can we un-dupe this one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Debian (and derivatives) use the `iptables-persistent` package for this task.

Define your rules in `/etc/iptables/rules.4` and/or `/etc/iptables/rules.6` and activate the service (using `update-rc.d`, `chkconfig` or your tool of choice.

On RHEL and derivatives, the startup script `/etc/init.d/iptables` reads `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`, so you need to define your rules there, and ensure that the `iptables` service is activated (`chkconfig iptables on`) and started (`service iptables start`).

Comment: Ty for this tipp. Do you know how to do it with Red Hat derivates as well? This Amazon VPC Image is based on red hat

Answer (score 19):

```
service iptables save
```

or

```
/etc/init.d/iptables save
```

Comment: did the trick on my EC2 instance!

Comment: Says unrecognized service on my aws ami.

Comment: Where does it save it to?

Comment: If memory serves; /etc/sysconfig/iptables